# Read or select value names from .json file to push in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node.js-fs

if `myjson.js` file data:

```
{
  "key1": [
    {
      "name1": [
        "word1",
        "word2",
      ],
      "name2": [
        "word3",
        "word4",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

loaded:

```
  var jsonData = fs.readFileSync("myjson.json", "utf8");
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

output:

```
[ 'key1' ]
```

or:

```
 console.log(Object.values(data));
```

output:

```
[
  [
    {
      name1: [Array],  
      name2: [Array],  
    }
  ]
]
```

How properly read or select only value names (without 'value' values - arrays) to create  array of value names:

```
[
   "name1",  
   "name2",  
]
```

Comment: Using `Object.keys` is correct, but you need to select the correct object to get the keys from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all the keys in the array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452572/finding-all-the-keys-in-the-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#flatMap` over each of the arrays of objects.

```js
const data={key1:[{name1:["word1","word2",],name2:["word3","word4",]}]};
let res = Object.values(data).flatMap(x => x.flatMap(Object.keys));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note `key1` is actually an array.

```js
const obj = {
  "key1": [
    {
      "name1": [
        "word1",
        "word2",
      ],
      "name2": [
        "word3",
        "word4",
      ]
    }
  ]
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj.key1[0]));
```